# Angular2 template field issue

Tags: angular

I am getting spacing issue with the template field in Angular2

This is my code.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: ' <h1 class="test">
                   Angular 2 Template    
                </h1>',
    styleUrls: ['./assets/style.css']
})
```

This does not work

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: ' <h1 class="test">Angular 2 Template</h1>',
    styleUrls: ['./assets/style.css']
})
```

This works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you should use the ES6 backtick "`" for [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
Component({
        selector: 'my-component',
        template: ` <h1 class="test">
                       Angular 2 Template    
                    </h1>`,
        styleUrls: ['./assets/style.css']
    })
```